# pdf generation from serial letter word template with merge fields

Tags: ruby, ms-word, pdf-generation

I need to generate pdfs from serial letter templates containing merge fields in ms/oo word format. The app should be running on a debian linux server. Only opensource or free tools should be used.

What's the best (command line?) tool chain to use? I'd prefer a pure ruby solution if it exists. :)

Comment: If you convert your templates to PDFs with form fields, you'll have more options.  PDF form field fillers are fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) for all my ruby-based PDF generation needs.